# CDC data mirroring issue RA MSG 2023

Tags: cdc

I am beginner to CDC data mirror target.
I was told to bring up a data mirror target to send data from one iseries to another.
When I tried to start the data mirror, I got below message

RA MSG 2023  Error occurred during journal validation and processing. Please see previous messages for detail

Looks like the file that needs to be journaled is missing its journal position

Since my team is also new to this, none of them helped me. Wondering if you guys can help me out.

Please feel free to let me know if you need more details

Thank you and Regards
Saiprasad